# socket io on() function client could not get last updated states of redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, socket.io

I want to update tempID after created message in socket io server.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const inboxStates = useSelector((state) => state.inbox);
const socketRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  socketRef.current = io.connect("http://localhost:5000");

  console.log(inboxStates); // {1: {body:"hello", createdAt: "2021-06-17 12:03:35"}, tempID:{body:"hello2", createdAt: "2021-06-17 12:03:35"} }
  socketRef.current.on("created-message", ({ results, messageData }) => {
    console.log(inboxStates); // {} should be exactly like two lines higher but returns {}
  });
}, [inboxStates]);
```

but it returns `{}` in `on()` function. Any ideas?
Thanks!